# Further define Cascade Object Detector

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, cascade, feature-detection

I have code that is supposed to detect every musical note on a piece of sheet music, but the results with the object detector does not match any of the notes.

**Code**:

```
load('noterecognition.mat');
posDir = fullfile('D:','Tom','Documents','MATLAB','Music Reader','raw');
addpath(posDir);
negDir = fullfile('D:','Tom','Documents','MATLAB','Music Reader','bad');
trainCascadeObjectDetector('noteDetector.xml',positiveInstances,negDir,...
                           'FalseAlarmRate',0.2,'NumCascadeStages',5);

detector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('noteDetector.xml'); 

img = imread('jazzpolice.jpg');
%img = imbinarize(img);
bbox = step(detector,img);

detectedImg = insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bbox,'note');

figure;
imshow(detectedImg);
```

Here are the other parts:

[image]

LEFT Image Trainer (I highlighted each note as a positive)
MIDDLE Image for Detection
RIGHT Result

As you can see it's not what I wanted as a result.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT** Here are my negative samples: [http://imgur.com/gallery/R9Gb9](https://imgur.com/gallery/R9Gb9)

Comment: What kind of positive samples did you provide? Also, how many sheets did you provide as a training set?

Comment: As you can see in the image above, I highlighted each note on the sheet. Regarding the sheets, I don't know what you mean. Sheets of music?

Comment: I'm sorry, wrote it wrong.  That should be "negative samples". What kind of negative samples did you provide?  I'm asking this, because as far as I see, the algorithm tends to find a lot of false positives. `negDir = fullfile('D:','Tom','Documents','MATLAB','Music Reader','bad');` In this line, you provide some negative samples. However, they are not shown in your question. Maybe, there is a problem here. If you label some negative samples, the result may be improved.

Comment: Ah ok. From what I read, the negative samples shouldn't be labelled in the same way as the positives. I've just got a folder of things like sharps, flats etc.
I'll try it and see what it does

Comment: I added my negative samples to the post. Still couldn't get it to work :/